# How do I get on the internet in a 3rd world country?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection, satellite, cellular-internet

My girlfriend is doing peacekeeping work in Rwanda and she has very poor internet access and it's difficult to stay in touch.

What technologies or resources are available for non-connected or remote locations?

Comment: telephone and mail?

Comment: Don't forget courier service

Comment: What does she currently use?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is either too localized to a certain country and will constantly need to be updated, or we'd have to maintain a list for *all* 3rd world countries. Moreover, this isn't really a question about a computer hardware or software problem, just about what ISPs are there in what country.

Answer (score 2):

Africa has some of the best 3G and 4G networks in the world. MTN has a massive presence in the african continent. Get a 3G data contract through MTN, you'll get a 3G modem to use with the laptop.

http://www.mtn.co.rw/Content/Pages/70/MTN_Unlimited_Internet_Access

Answer (score -2):

Consider pay 4G ADSL acess for your gf.
I do not know where are rwanda, my best guess it is afrika.
But, if in Brazil all public schools has optical fibre and wireless for free, be sure, no place on earth is far enough to haven't ADSL.

Comment: Is not taking the time to look up where Rwanda is grounds for flagging as low quality? It is in my opinion. There's a certain level of knowledge I expect to see in any SU answer, and this just doesn't cut it for me. Further, the assertion that "no place on earth is far enough to haven't ADSL" does nothing constructive to answer the question.